# Jupyter Notebook virtual environment kernel broken: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, virtual-environment

I recently modified my conda virtual environment to try installing a package (openjpeg) because of issues I was running into with pydicom. I restarted my Jupyter Notebook, but then it seemed something I did completely messed up my ability to load the environment in Jupyter Notebook.  I tried recreating the environment from scratch and manually installing my needed packages, but got the same error.  After I load jupyter notebook from command line and open my .ipynb file using the environment kernel, I get the error copied below in the cmd/miniconda window:

```
[I 00:22:55.851 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Py36Base\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[W 00:22:58.870 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 00:22:58.870 NotebookApp] Kernel 30d40c82-f840-47cc-8192-54aeb028d1aa died, removing from map.
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this? I saw some posts with similar errors (but different issue overall) and the most comomon solution was making sure the Anaconda system environment PATH variable is set (which it is). For the record I'm running Windows 10 and latest Anaconda install (first environment using Python 3.8, re-built environment using Python 3.6). If you think I should copy my conda list output for the virtual environment let me know

Answer (score 0):

It seems a rather simple fix was to activate the environment and then run jupyter notebook. That seemed to stop the error. Was not aware this was a requirement?